# Why does registers exists and how they work together with cpu?

Tags: operating-system, hardware, ram, cpu-registers

So I am currently learning Operating Systems and Programming.

I want how the registers work in detail.

All I know is there is the main memory and our CPU which takes address and instruction from the main memory by the help of the address bus.

And also there is something MCC  (Memory Controller Chip which helps in fetching the memory location from RAM.)

On the internet, it shows register is temporary storage and data can be accessed faster than ram for registers.

But I want to really understand the deep-down process on how they work. As they are also of 32 bits and 16 bits something like that. I am really confused.!!!

Comment: 'But I want to really understand the deep-down process on how they work', well, you will need considerable knowledge of hardware, electronics, physics/quantum mechanics, CPU architecture.  Can you narrow down your question a bit, (lot)?

Comment: Yes, you must narrow down your question.

Comment: All am I asking is what is registers. I looking for detail explanation on how this things works with CPU and main memory

Comment: The term to Google for is 'CPU registers'

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a native english speaker, pardon me for some perhaps incorrect terminology. Hope this will be a little bit helpful.

> Why does registers exists

When user program is running on CPU, it works in a 'dynamic' sense. That is, we should store incoming source data or any intermediate data, and do specific calculation upon them. Memory devices are needed. We have a choice among flip-flop, on-chip RAM/ROM, and off-chip RAM/ROM.

The term `register` for programmer's model is actually a D flip-flop in the physical circuit, which is a memory device and can hold a single bit. An IC design consists of standard cell part (including the `register` mentioned before, and `and`/`or`/etc. gates) and hard macro (like SRAM). As the technology node advances, the standard cells' delay are getting smaller and smaller. Auto Place-n-Route tool will place the `register` and the related surrounding logic nearby, to make sure the logic can run at the specified 3.0/4.0GHz speed target. For some practical reasons (which I'm not quite sure because I don't do layout), we tend to place hard macros around, leading to much longer metal wire. This plus SRAM's own characteristics, on-chip SRAM is normally slower than D flip-flop. If the memory device is off the chip, say an external Flash chip or KGD (known good die), it will be further slower since the signals should traverse through 2 more IO devices which have much larger delay.

> how they work together with cpu

Each `register` is assigned a different 'address' (which maybe not open to programmer). That is implemented by adding address decode logic. For instance, when CPU is going to execute an instruction `mov R1, 0x12`, the address decode logic sees the binary code of `R1`, and selects only those flip-flops corresponding to `R1`. Then data `0x12` is stored (written) into those flip-flops. Same for read process.

Regarding "they are also of 32 bits and 16 bits something like that", the bit width is not a problem. Both flip-flops and a word in RAM can have a bit width of `N`, as long as the same address can select `N` flip-flops or `N` bits in RAM at one time.

Answer (score 0):

Registers are small memories which resides inside the processor (what you called CPU). Their role is to hold the operands for fast processor calculations and to store the results. A register is usually designated by a name (AL, BX, ECX, RDX, cr3, RIP, R0, R8, R15, etc.) and has a size which is the number of bits it can store (4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 bits). Other registers have special meanings, and their bits control the state or provide information about the state of the processor.

There are not many registers (because they are very expensive). All of them have a capacity of only a few kilobytes, so they can't store all the code and data of your program, which can go up to gigabytes. This is the role of the central memory (what you call RAM). This big memory can hold gigabytes of data and each byte has its address. However, it only holds data when the computer is turned on. The RAM reside outside of the CPU Chip and interacts with him via Memory Controller Chip which stands as interface between CPU and RAM.
On top of that, there is the hard drive that stores your data when you turn off your computer.
That is a very simple view to get you started.